# Is multithreading with webworkers ineffective?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a project in which I have to process quite large objects, each taking about 500ms. I thought that using web workers would greatly speed up this process. But after playing around with web workers, they didn't seem to improve the speed at all - even if I took away the preprocessing the creation of the web workers.

So I decided to create a simple example: there is an array with `N` numbers, and the sum of those numbers should be calculated.

So first, **without** webworkers ([**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/wagenaartje/ooduhb5h/3/)):

```
/** Goal: return sum of all numbers in array */
var numbers = [];

for(var i = 0; i < N; i++){
    numbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}

/** Test without web workers */
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    total += numbers[i];
}
```

Then, **with** webworkers ([**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/wagenaartje/ooduhb5h/3/)):

```
/** Options */
var WORKERS = 5; // N should be divisble by WORKERS

/** Test WITH web workers */
var workers = [];

var source = `
onmessage = function(e) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < e.data.length; i++){
    total += e.data[i];
  }
    postMessage(total);
}`

for(var i = 0; i < WORKERS; i++){
  var blob = new Blob([source]);
  var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  let worker = new Worker(blobURL);

  worker.onmessage = function(e){
    total += e.data;
    worker.terminate();
    if(++finished == workers.length) done();
  }

  workers.push(worker);
}

var finished = 0;
var chunk = Math.floor(N / WORKERS);

var sliced = [];
for(var i = 0; i < workers.length; i++){
    sliced.push(numbers.slice(i*chunk,i*chunk+chunk));
}

// we calculate time after we created the workers, from here
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < workers.length; i++){
  workers[i].postMessage(sliced[i]);
}

function done(){
  // do something
}
```

So the results: webworkers seem to be completely disastrous. It's over 10x slower than without webworkers.

So my question, can anyone show me an example where multithreading with webworkers is actually faster? I'm failing to see the point of webworkers besides running without affecting the UI....

**Edit:** it runs over way slower, but the CPU usage is way higher (100% with, ~30% without webworkers) - it makes me question where all that power is going to

**Edit 2:** Even when you leave the `onmessage` on the worker side do nothing, it still runs way slower... it seems like the communication between the main thread and the worker thread is just incredibly slow ([see for yourself](https://jsfiddle.net/wagenaartje/ooduhb5h/4/))

**Edit 3:** it's not related to `postMessage`,  I have measured performance and it's nothing I can do about by coding differently. The weirdest thing of all: when I measure performance with Google chrome dev tools, it runs almost 2x as fast

Interesting [article](http://calvinmetcalf.com/post/55957954794/web-workers-are-slower-and-thats-ok):

Comment: WebWorkers don't magically make things that normally take 500ms take less than 500ms. It just runs the code on a separate thread so that the UI thread can continue doing it's thing.

Comment: I would suspect that the slicing alone is more work than simple summing.

Comment: Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39419116/215552

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the tip, in the new demo it's preprocessed

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan so that's my question... is there anything else that's useful about webworkers apart from the fact that they don't affect UI

Comment: @ThomasW for one thing in chrome they run properly when the tab is not focused whereas `setInterval` doesn't.

Comment: Yes, webworkers can take advantage of multiple cores.

Comment: @torazaburo I know, but give an example where webworker is actually faster.

Comment: @torazaburo take a look at the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wagenaartje/ooduhb5h/3/) - worker creation and blob creation and any preprocessig is not included in the timings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your benchmark is being swamped by the cost of transferring ten million numbers to each worker.

Instead, create a `ArrayBuffer`. Pass that, as part of `transferList` (the second parameter to `postMessage`). On my machine the workers run this job in less than 100ms compared to 200ms without the workers.

See https://jsfiddle.net/ooduhb5h/7/.

Comment: Is there any way to convert an object to a buffer?

Comment: @ThomasW No, there's not. Basically, web workers are at their best when they are doing lots of computation based on relatively small amounts of input.